# Can we test web service of sharepoint 2010 in postman?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can we test web service of sharepoint 2010 in postman?
If yes, Can we get the list item of sharepoint 2010 using microsoft by default web service with postman?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint exposes a REST API as well as several webservice endpoints...

So most likely you can test them as much as you desire. But these endpoints have been tested a lot by Microsoft already, and you only would be running tests that have been passing anyway. (If you just want to test those end points I mean) If you want to test the result of your code, then this can be a very valid approach.

Here is some info about those REST endpoints:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

Comment: Sure, as long as you can authenticate...